# XSL - Make element mandatory based on other element availability

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am creating a XSD based on the below Xml using a XSL file. Actually I want to make Element2 block mandatory (minOccurs=1) only when Element1 block is available in each node (Sample, Sample1, etc..). If Element1 block is not available then Element2 block should become optional (minOccurs=0). I tried ancestor::*[*], match etc., but nothing is working. Please help.

### Xml

```
<Root>
  <Sample>
      <Element1>
        <SubElement1>0</SubElement1>
      </Element1>
      <Element2>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>2</Y>
      </Element2>
    </Sample>
    <Sample1>
      <Element2>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>2</Y>
      </Element2>
    </Sample1>
</Root>
```

### XSL

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="(local-name() = 'Element2' and //*[matches(local-name(), 'Element1')])">
       <xs:element name="{local-name()}" minOccurs="1">
          <xsl:call-template name="renderChildElements" />
        </xs:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xs:element name="{local-name()}" minOccurs="0">
            <xsl:call-template name="renderChildElements" />
          </xs:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

<xsl:template name="renderChildElements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all minOccurs="0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </xs:all>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you provide an example of the desired output? and maybe a more complete stylesheet?

Comment: Generating a schema that's specific to one XML instance seems a very odd thing to do. What are you trying to achieve? Surely there are tools that do this better?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you only want to make `Element2` have `minOccurs="1"` when it has an `Element1` sibling?

The XPath `//*[matches(local-name(), 'Element1')])` is using the descendant axis, so it is jumping up to the top of the XML tree and looking through the entire document to test whether there is an `Element1` element.

Instead, you want to constrain it to just the elements under the `Element2` parent: `..//*[local-name() eq 'Element1']` or if you just care about the children of the parent of `Element2` you could use: `../*[local-name() eq 'Element1']`

I think you can further simplify and consolidate, and move the conditional logic inside of the minOccurs attribute, using an attribute value template to compute the value of either `1` or `0`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xs:element name="{local-name()}" 
      minOccurs="{if (local-name() = 'Element2' and ..//*[local-name() eq 'Element1']) then 1 else 0}">
      <xsl:call-template name="renderChildElements" />
    </xs:element>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template name="renderChildElements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all minOccurs="0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </xs:all>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```